# Issues with ActiveLabel.swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uilabel

I am using "ActiveLabel.swift" from [github](https://github.com/optonaut/ActiveLabel.swift). It seems when I create a UIViewRepresentable there is always space above or below the text:

There is very large space above "Hashtag test..."

[image]

I would like to know if there is any way to get rid of the empty space. To be more specific, I would like to have the text right below comment and like buttons.

Here is the code I used to create ActiveLabel:

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ActiveLabel {
        let label = ActiveLabel()
        label.enabledTypes = [.mention, .hashtag, .url]
        label.text = contentString
        label.textColor = .black
        label.hashtagColor = .systemBlue
        label.handleHashtagTap { hashtag in
            hashtagTapped = hashtag
            goToHashtag = true
        }
        print(contentString)
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = size
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.sizeToFit()

        return label
    }
```

and use above view:

```
var body: some View {

        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            let stuff = content == "" ? "" : content
            HashtagActiveLabelView(goToHashtag: $goToHashtag, hashtagTapped: $hashtagTapped, contentString: stuff, size: size)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                .padding()
        }
```

I have tried to use methods such as sizeToFit but could not figure this problem out.

Comment: It works for me in UIKit, I think your constraint is wrong ".fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)", remove sizeToFit and change your vertical fixedSize, your vertical should be flexible, and also your VStack Should be check